# How can i show and interact with points of interest (pois) on Here Maps on an Android application?

Tags: java, android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I'm creating an application on Android in JAVA which is uses Here Maps.
What I'm trying to do is to add pois by categories when zooming in and get coordinates when clicking on one of them.

I tried to create a custom map style using Map Style Editor to add it in the app via loadScene method, but I can't understand how that ΥΑΜL thing works.

Is this the right way to do it?
What other choices do I have?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which edition are you using? For Explore / Navigate you can pick the embedded POIs that are shown by default on any map. Of course, you can also add your own POIs by using MapMarker class.

Comment: @Datasun i'm using the lite version but i'm interesting in what you say. could you give me a link or generally further information?

Comment: @Tomjs2400, the Lite Edition does not allow to pick the default POIs, but with Explore/Navigate, you can see here how it can be done: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#pick-embedded-pois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map Styling is one the key factor to make the map more  interactive and meaningful. Styling varies from customer to customer. Keeping all these points in mind ,we have   made the architecture in such a way that the customer can give his own
Styling configuration file and that could be loaded on run time. The most flexible solution to customize the map is to create your own map styles using a configuration file written in the YAML markup format. YAML is a digestible data serialization language that is often utilized to create configuration files and works in concurrence with any programming language.

Currently we are providing two options for custom Styling.

1>Create and Load Custom Map Styles.

The most flexible solution to customize the map is to create your own map styles using a configuration file written in the YAML markup format. Which is similar to JSON format.Such files can be generated with a WYSIWYG map style editor provided by HERE. For login, please use your HERE credentials (access_key_id / access_key_secret).
https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/#12.528/52.5309/13.3848

2>Load Custom Raster Layers.

Another alternative to customize the map's look is to add your own raster tile service on top of the HERE map styles. This can be your own server where you host tiles that you want to show as an overlay on top of selected areas of the world - or a public tile server such as OpenStreetMap.

For more details and examples please refer below link.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.9.2.0/dev_guide/topics/custom-map-styles-lite.html